# How to provide S3 path as input to HadoopJarStep while using RunJobFlow in EMR?

Tags: pyspark, boto3, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to run `spark-submit` while adding a step using `run_job_flow` creating a new EMR cluster from boto3. I am trying to provide a file from **S3** using `s3 file path` in `Args`. Here's how I did it-

```
'Args': ['spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://{Bucket}/{path}']
```

Here's the `stderr` output in EMR console-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://{Bucket}/{path}" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.CommandRunner.main(CommandRunner.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster s3://{Bucket}/{path}" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.command.runner.ProcessRunner.exec(ProcessRunner.java:92)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What are the other parameter values of HadoopJarStepConfig?